# React export {...} from shorhand usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### When using

```
export { module } from 'path'
```

This doesn't work specially with default exports

but when importing then exporting no problem
in *index.js*

```
import module from path  
export {module}
```

I'm i missing something

Comment: hey guys mostly this is a syntax issue am not aware of 
i was watching a video tutorial and he used it no need for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-export a default export as a named one, you can use the following syntax

```js
export {default as module} from './path
```

Alternatively, if you want to export all named export in a single export, you can use

```js
export {* as module} from './path'
```

Answer (score -1):

> Simply because this syntax does not deal with default exports only named ones